# All margins should be at least 15 mm (not including any footers or headers)

Tags: margins, fancyhdr, geometry

I'm writing an important proposal, and here is the required formatting:

> Page limit: 20 pages
>
> The minimum font size allowed is 11 points
>
> The reference font for the body text of proposals is Times New Roman
> (Windows platforms), Times/Times New Roman (Apple platforms) or Nimbus
> Roman No. 9 L (Linux distributions).
>
> The page size
> is A4, and all margins (top, bottom, left, right) should be at least
> 15 mm (not including any footers or headers).

I have already written a draft, which has far more than 20 pages. So besides cutting content, I would like to **hold as much text as possible** while satisfying the required formatting conditions.

First, the requirement is not very very clear to me, could anyone tell me if the 15 mm margin can contain headers/footers or not?

Second, at the moment, I have the following MWE, which does not respect the required margin condition. Could anyone help me build an MWE that respects the exact required margins while trying to hold as much text as possible?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4]{article}

\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\textwidth}{170mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{245mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-2mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-2mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-10mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{3mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{4mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-5mm}

\lhead{\lhead{Author}}
\rhead{\thepage}
\chead{Title}
% Foot
\rfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
1 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

2 \lipsum*[1]

3 \lipsum*[1]

4 \lipsum*[1]

5 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

6 \lipsum*[1]

7 \lipsum*[1]

8 \lipsum*[1]

\pagestyle{fancy}
9 \lipsum*[1]

10 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

11 \lipsum*[1]

12 \lipsum*[1]

13 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

14 \lipsum*[1]

15 \lipsum*[1]

16 \lipsum*[1]

17 \lipsum*[1]

18 \lipsum*[1]

19 \lipsum*[1]

20 \lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Use the package `geometry` to set the margins instead of `\setlength{<everything>}`. There are tons of examples in this site and do not forget take a look to the manual.  (2) To me the requirement is clear: You can include header or footer, but it can not be count as part of the already ridiculous 15 mm margin (3) Hold as many texts as possible  is probably the worst strategy from all the points of view. Left decent margins (> 2 cm) and rewrite the contents to make a more clear and brief document.

Comment: Off topic, but are you sure you want to use ISO-8859-1 aka Latin-1 encoding? That said, I agree with Fran: try not to cram as much text as possible into your proposal. Theoretically you could reduce font size, leading, etc. but at some point those are considered crimes against typography. Then again, 10pt instead of the 11pt you currently use might be fine …

Comment: You can of course have the pages with minimal margins, minimal fontsize, and maximum text but would anyone want to read that? The document needs to be pleasant to look at to encourage someone to read it. My "A Few Notes on Book Design" (`texdoc memdesign`) shows a variety of page layouts. Choose something that suits your text and audience.

Comment: If you use geometry, don' forget [noheadfoot] and \pagestyle{empty}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is `a4`, besides not using `geometry`. If you want A4 paper, the option is `a4paper`. The parameters are adapted to letter paper, which is wider and shorter than A4.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  heightrounded,
  headheight=13.6pt,
  headsep=11pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Author}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{Title}

\begin{document}

\layout

1 \lipsum*[1]%~\footnote{abc}

2 \lipsum*[1]

3 \lipsum*[1]

4 \lipsum*[1]

5 \lipsum*[1]%~\footnote{abc}

6 \lipsum*[1]

7 \lipsum*[1]

8 \lipsum*[1]

\pagestyle{fancy}
9 \lipsum*[1]

10 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

11 \lipsum*[1]

12 \lipsum*[1]

13 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

14 \lipsum*[1]

15 \lipsum*[1]

16 \lipsum*[1]

17 \lipsum*[1]

18 \lipsum*[1]

19 \lipsum*[1]

20 \lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

I used `layout` to get a picture showing the lengths.

For instance, we see

① `one inch + \hoffset`
③ `\oddsidemargin = -29pt`

Actually, `\oddsidemargin` is `-29.59087pt` and `72.27-29.59087` points is exactly `15mm`. The text width is `512pt` (actually `512.14963pt`) which is `180mm` and the right margin is `210-180-15=15` millimeters.

Similarly, ② is one inch; the `\topmargin` is `-54.19087pt`; considering `\headheight` and `\headsep`, you get the top margin exactly at 15mm from the top of the page. The text height is computed as `759.00034pt`, which is `266.76mm`, so the bottom margin is

```
297 - 266.76 - 15 = 15.24
```

millimeters. It's better to use `heightrounded`, so an integral number of lines fits the page. As you see, you're still respecting the requirements. Not really so important, however, because `article` with the default `oneside` option uses `\raggedbottom`; it would be necessary if `twoside` is issued.

Fix the `headsep` to suit your taste, but leave `headheight=13.6pt` or `fancyhdr` might change the page parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your precise answer. To calculate the top margin, you used ② - ④ + ⑤ + ⑥, which is approximately `72pt-54pt+13pt+11pt=42pt`, which is about 15mm. So your top margin did cover the header area. Are you sure this respects the requirement, a.k.a, "all margins (top, bottom, left, right) should be at least 15 mm (**not including any footers or headers**)"?

Comment: @SoftTimur It depends on how you interpret “not including”.

Comment: I will double check with the organisation. You confirm that your top margin did cover the header area, right?

Comment: @SoftTimur That's how I read it: the top of the text block should be at least 15mm from the top of the page, headers aren't considered. Apparently they want to set some limitations on the text, confirmed by setting a maximum number of pages. Headers and footers don't count in the number of words.

Comment: I just sent a mail to the organisation, i will come back to you, thank you.

Comment: Hello, the organisation has not replied to my mail. Do you mind appending an answer where headers are not covered by the 15 mm?

Comment: Additionally, I just printed the pdf on an A4 paper and measured it with a ruler. I realised that e.g., for Page 2, the left margin is about `16.5mm` and the right margin is about `18mm`. Is it normal that the left margin is NOT equal to the right margin, whereas we did not specify that in the latex code?

Comment: @SoftTimur Quite likely your printer driver applied a reduction to 97.5% (printer drivers often do that). Please check.

Comment: @SoftTimur For keeping the header below the 15mm space at the top, simply add the `includehead` option.

Comment: i just printed it on a `A4 borderless` by setting scale to `100%` with `\usepackage[a4paper,margin=15mm,heightrounded,headheight=13.6pt,headsep=11pt,includehead]{geometry}`, the left and right margin are now equal, but they are about `13mm` rather than `15mm` https://ibb.co/Gd4pFSH, do you know why?

Comment: @SoftTimur No. I measured the PDF with Acrobat Reader and the margins show OK.

Comment: That's true, i re-printed the paper, they were all about 15mm. I notice that for a page with 2 footnotes for instance, the bottom margin is quite big (0.74inch) https://ibb.co/DYxTW1c, is it normal? is it possible to set it as 15mm as well?

Comment: @SoftTimur That depends on several factors; for instance the footnote marks fall near the bottom or an orphan line might be produced and so on. Very long lines tend to form two- or three-line paragraphs that make it likely to get orphans.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the `geometry` package, for a detailed explanation on its features, check the [documentation](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) (it's 42 pages, but only the first 17 have information on the package, the rest is the implementation.) For example you could say `\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}`. If you want to make sure the header and footer length aren't included, you could also put `includehead` and `includefoot`, which will put the headers and footers inside the text body, separate from the margins. I'd also recommend editing your paper well to make it concise so that it can fit in the 20 pages, as Fran said in the comments. Based on the required font size an margins, I'm not sure of anyway to fit more text in the pages (although someone else may know a way.)

Comment: I tried `\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm,includehead,includefoot,showframe]{geometry}`, the returned layout returned a big margin below the header and above the main text.

Comment: Good point, try also putting headsep=0pt. That should fix it, did it work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you gave is the exact solution. I tried `\usepackage[lmargin=15mm,rmargin=15mm,tmargin=\dimexpr15mm+1.5\baselineskip,bmargin=\dimexpr15mm+1.5\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip,headsep=.5\baselineskip,footskip=1.5\baselineskip]{geometry}`, which returned a different result than `\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm,includehead,includefoot,headsep=.5\baselineskip]{geometry}`. Do you know which one answers exactly my question?

Comment: I actually changed my mind, I think the headers and footers can be included in the margins, including those or removing those won't change the width/height of the total margin. `headsep` only controls the distance from the header to the top barrier of the text body, but doesn't change the height of the top margin. Same with marginparsep,which controls the distance between the "margin notes" and the right barrier of the text body (this is according to the geometry documentation). So the full code is `\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}`. I think that's all you need.

Comment: You could also shorten that to `\usepackage[vmargin=15mm,hmargin=15mm]{geometry}` which achieves the same thing.

Comment: Even shorter: `\usepackage[margin={15mm,15mm}]{geometry}` (sorry I know this is unnecessary).

Answer (score 3):

I'd definitely use `geometry` to set correct margins. If you want to include headers, use `inlcudehead`. Otherwise, use `nohead` to save space. It is similar with `inlcudefoot` and `nofoot` (see pages 5-10 in [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry)).

Another option is to use `titleformat`/`titlespacing` from `titlesec` and remove/reduce the top space occupied by chapter titles.

In order to keep the same or empty page style on pages with chapter titles (standard is `plain`), `\chapter` needs to be patched

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{}{}
```

or change `empty` to anything else, perhaps `fancy`.

Hope it helps

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[
    margin=15mm,
    headheight=14.5pt,
    headsep=\normalbaselineskip,
    includehead, nofoot, nomarginpar, % nohead,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\me}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[C]{\mytitle}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{}{}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Huge}{Chapter \thechapter}{3pt}{\Huge}
    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*-4}{*6}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}   % Add doc. frames for a reference
    \renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
    \renewcommand{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{blue}}

\newcommand\mytitle{My Proposal}
\newcommand{\me}{F. Surname}
\title{\mytitle}
\author{\me}
\date{}

\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}
% \maketitle
\chapter{First}
\blindtext[1]\footnote{abc}

\blindmathtrue\Blinddocument\footnote{def}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using OpTeX then you can declare:

```
\fontfam[Times]
\typosize[11/13]
\margins/1 a4 (15,15,15,15)mm

\lorem[1-150] \lorem[1-50] % 20 pages
\bye
```